# mysql, compact a query using case and variables

Tags: mysql

i've a query like this: subqueries are made to different tables depending on a CASE choice.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    UNID,
    IDMENU,
    IDTYPE, ( CASE WHEN `IDMENU` = 1 THEN
            (
                SELECT
                    tableB.DESCRIPTION
                FROM
                    tableB
                WHERE
                    tableB.ID = tableA.ID
                    AND tableB.IDMENU = tableA.IDMENU
                    AND tableB.IDTYPE = tableA.IDTYPE)
                WHEN `IDMENU` = 2 THEN
                (
                    SELECT
                        tableC.DESCRIPTION
                    FROM
                        tableC
                    WHERE
                        tableC.ID = tableA.ID
                        AND tableC.IDMENU = tableA.IDMENU
                        AND tableC.IDTYPE = tableA.IDTYPE)
END) AS DESCRIPTION
FROM
    tableA
```

could this be more compact? can i have a CASE saving value into a variable and then use the variable as table name? should i use a procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Subqueries, you can use `Left Join` instead. `Left Join` would ensure that all the rows from your primary (leftmost) table do appear.

```
SELECT
    tA.ID,
    tA.UNID,
    tA.IDMENU,
    tA.IDTYPE, 
    (CASE tA.IDMENU
       WHEN 1 THEN tB.DESCRIPTION
       WHEN 2 THEN tC.DESCRIPTION) AS DESCRIPTION 
FROM
    tableA AS tA 
LEFT JOIN tableB AS tB ON tB.ID = tA.ID AND 
                          tB.IDMENU = tA.IDMENU AND 
                          tB.IDTYPE = tA.IDTYPE 
LEFT JOIN tableC AS tC ON tC.ID = tA.ID AND 
                          tC.IDMENU = tA.IDMENU AND 
                          tC.IDTYPE = tA.IDTYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below query by using case when

```
SELECT
   ID,
   UNID,
   IDMENU,
   IDTYPE,
   case 
     when IDMENU=1 then tableB.DESCRIPTION 
     when IDMENU=2 then tableC.DESCRIPTION 
   end as description
   FROM TableA 
   left join tableB on 
        tableB.ID = tableA.ID AND 
        tableB.IDMENU = tableA.IDMENU AND 
        tableB.IDTYPE = tableA.IDTYPE
   left join tableC on 
        tableC.ID = tableA.ID AND 
        tableC.IDMENU = tableA.IDMENU AND 
        tableC.IDTYPE = tableA.IDTYPE
```